# Azure Data Factory Expression Builder string formatting Error: unrecognised token (new line)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Mapping Data Flow, where I want to use a custom SQL query for the Source, but I cannot break it on multiple lines, I get an error stating:

> token recognition error at: ''

If I remove the newline and put the whole query on a single line it works, but it looks bearly readable. I would like to preserve the query formatting.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

LE the same happens with a simple statement like

```
select
1
```

[image]

This is how it looks in ADF:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter a query directly into the SQL Query box as multi-lines (see image). You only need to use the expression builder or dynamic content if you are going to use expressions or parameters.

[image]

Comment: But if you add in parameters or expressions in dynamic content, it will get treated as a single-line string.

Comment: you are correct, after removing the expression I was able to insert a query on multiple lines. it breaks my mojo when I have to put everything on a single line for using parameters or expressions, as a long time SQL dev, but I will live with it.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can get more information on what is allowed as a Source query - I cannot find anywhere the information that CTEs are not allowed, although that is as true as it can be indeed.

Comment: We haven't listed a complete set of SQL operations not supported in data flow source today. But we are adding stored proc support soon, which will help when using source pushdown operations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#source-transformation

Comment: So with expressions multiline SQL is not possible?

Comment: I solved it by adding some logic outside the initial query logic and by placing all the dynamic parts inside the flow's logic.

Comment: @Benedikt Would you mind elaborating how you were able to achieve your workaround? Thanks!

Comment: I kept the query without any dynamic parts. And added additional steps in the data flow to filter or do other stuff inside the following steps in the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CTEs in ADF data flow source queries, that's the issue.

Comment: OK, I understand the CTE not being supported, but even a simple "select
1" returns the same error - is the multiple line format not supported?

Comment: but the select is not working, see my edited screenshot above

Comment: I think the real question here is what can be used as a line continuation character when building a multi-line string expression in mapping data flows.  His example of simple SELECT 1" that spans two lines sums it up.  I'm facing the same issue when building a large dynamic pre-sql statement and don't want the whole thing on one line.