# are multiline sql statements possible in visual expression builder in data flows?

Tags: azure-data-factory

The source in my dataflow is a sql server, and i am obtaining the data using a sql query.
The Visual expression builder throws errors and says the expression is incorrect if i try to do this over multiline (see below images).

Am i doing something incorrectly, or does the IDE still not allow multi line statements?

[image]

Single line, no errors

[image]

multi line - errors on each line break

Comment: You may want to try to use `@concat` like "multiline support in expresssions" section in [this blog](http://datanrg.blogspot.com/2021/01/these-little-things-about-azure-data.html)

Comment: Hm this is about 'pipeline expression builder' not flows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Data Factory Expression Builder string formatting Error: unrecognised token (new line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452496/azure-data-factory-expression-builder-string-formatting-error-unrecognised-toke)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @ray & @Benedikt for your valuable input, posting it as an answer to help other community members.

If you use a direct query without including parameters, you can write your multi-line SQL query in the source query builder.

[image]

Use visual expression builder if you want to pass the query dynamically to include expression elements.

Here, use Concat() function to build a multi-line query in the expression builder.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue anymore. I am receiving an error "token recognition error at: '\\\\n'\\n"